# why Selenium python write only first row of csv where my scraper collecting multiple row data?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to collect data from websites. Where my scraper collected multiple row data but my csv file write only the first row. here is my code:

```
for page in range(1,34):
    url = ('my website url')
     
    driver.get(url)
    company_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.partner-name--text')
    if company_name:
           company_name = company_name.text
    else:
            company_name = "Not Found"
    
   header = ['company_name']
   data = [company_name]
   with open('sap.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)

            # write the header
            writer.writerow(header)

            # write the data
            writer.writerow(data)
   driver.quit()
```

I am collecting multiple company names but in my csv file only seeing the first company name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-writing the file many times instead of appending it:

```
data = []
for page in range(1,34):
    url = ('my website url')

    driver.get(url)
    company_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.partner-name--text')
    if company_name:
           company_name = company_name.text
    else:
            company_name = "Not Found"

   data.append(company_name)
   driver.quit() 

with open('sap.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(['company_name'])

    # write the data
    writer.writerows(data)
```